# Is it possible to directly call docker run from AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, amazon-ecs

I have a Java standalone application which I have dockerized. I want to run this docker everytime an object is put into S3 storage. On way is to do it via AWS batch which I am trying to avoid.

Is there a direct and easy way to call docker run from a lambda?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes and no.

What you can't do is execute `docker run` to run a container within the context of the Lambda call. But you can trigger a task on ECS to be executed. For this to work, you need to have a cluster set up on ECS, which means you need to pay for at least one EC2 instance. Because of that, it might be better to not use Docker, but I know too little about your application to judge that.

There are a lot of articles out there how to connect S3, Lambda and ECS. Here is a pretty in-depth article by Amazon that you might be interested in:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/better-together-amazon-ecs-and-aws-lambda/

If you are looking for code, this repository implements what is discussed in the above article:

https://github.com/awslabs/lambda-ecs-worker-pattern

Here is a snippet we use in our Lambda function (Python) to run a Docker container from Lambda:

```
result = boto3.client('ecs').run_task(
    cluster=cluster,
    taskDefinition=task_definition,
    overrides=overrides,
    count=1,
    startedBy='lambda'
)
```

We pass in the name of the `cluster` on which we want to run the container, as well as the task definition that defines which container to run, the resources it needs and so on. `overrides` is a dictionary/map with settings that you want to override in the task definition, which we use to specify the command we want to run (i.e. the argument to `docker run`). This enables us to use the same Lambda function to run a lot of different jobs on ECS.

Hope that points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It is possible to run containers out Docker images stored in Docker Hub within AWS Lambda using [SCAR](https://github.com/grycap/scar).

For example, you can create a Lambda function to execute a container out of the ubuntu:16.04 image in Docker Hub as follows:

```
scar init ubuntu:16.04
```

And then you can run a command or a shell-script within that container upon each invocation of the function:

```
scar run scar-ubuntu-16-04 whoami
SCAR: Request Id: ed5e9f09-ce0c-11e7-8375-6fc6859242f0
Log group name: /aws/lambda/scar-ubuntu-16-04
Log stream name: 2017/11/20/[$LATEST]7e53ed01e54a451494832e21ea933fca
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
sbx_user1059
```

You can use your own Docker images stored in Docker Hub. Some limitations apply but it can be effectively used to run generic applications on AWS Lambda. It also features a programming model for file-processing event-driven applications. It uses [uDocker](https://github.com/indigo-dc/udocker) under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

Yes try [**Udocker**](https://github.com/indigo-dc/udocker).

Udocker is a simple tool written in Python, it has a minimal set of dependencies so that can be executed in a wide range of Linux systems.

udocker does not make use of docker nor requires its installation.

udocker "executes" the containers by simply providing a chroot like environment over the extracted container. The current implementation uses PRoot to mimic chroot without requiring privileges.

Examples

Pull from docker hub and list the pulled images.

```
udocker pull  fedora
```

Create the container from a pulled image and run it.

```
udocker create --name=myfed  fedora
udocker run  myfed  cat /etc/redhat-release
```

And also its good to check [**Hackernoon**](https://hackernoon.com/how-did-i-hack-aws-lambda-to-run-docker-containers-7184dc47c09b).

Because: 
In Lambda, the only place you are allowed to write is /tmp. But udocker will attempt to write to the homedir by default. And other stuff.